# Laptop hot after format

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, overheating

I recently formatted an HP G62 Laptop and installed all drivers from the HP site that should be installed for this model.

But i noticed a very strange behavior, using Coretemp, the temp is always above 50 (on idle) and reaches 70 very quickly sometimes (Critical is 90)

If i open youtube or skype alone, i can get temperatures as high as 83.

Normally it was around 32 (on idle) and reaches 70 when i open games but not youtube....

I have a i3 processor and AMD graphics so i am wondering if somehow it's a graphics card issue (since i3 has integrated graphics as far as i know)

Device manager shows only AMD graphics card tho, not sure if i3 graphics should appear here too.

Any ideas what i might have forgotten to do after the format ?

Answer (score 1):

The other posters are right that excessive heat is usually the case of ventilation problems, but in your case that is not the case since reinstalling and OS does not add dust to fans and heatsinks.

What is likely is that you either:

1. Reinstalled and got another power plan (e.g. max performace settings in the current OS, max economy on the old one).
2. Or after reinstalling you might miss some additional software (older setups used some kind of cool-and-quiet software, but these days most of that is done without the need of installing additional programs).
3. Or the system is very busy indexing all files, updating .net caches, doing an initial virus scan, .... In which case the problem should go away after a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop is hot without appropriate load - it's usually ventilation issue. Laptop's ventilation will inevitably clog within a couple of years, depending on particular conditions.

Depending on the model, cleaning complexity varies. Sometimes it is easy to make yourself if you have special compartment that allows you reach the cooler. But usually it is quite difficult and it is better to put into service.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, i completely agree, but just before format, temperature readings were ok, it shouldn't jump from 35 to 50 in a week right ?

Comment: Yes, unlikely. But in this case, nothing else than a high load could heat him. Please, verify CPU load from all users, maybe some system process hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the heatsink and fan with a compresses can of air.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Source of Information](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c01657439)